# Python3.4 handling UTF encoded POST data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm using Python3.4 and the bottle web-framekwork to pass a filename via an AJAX POST request to a some python code that opens the file and works on it. However when the filename has non-english letters, like korean for example. I'm unable to open the file due to wrong path.

If i pass it with `escape()` in Javascript and then use `html.unescape()` in the python code, I get the slightly modified error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'C:\Data\[%uC9C1%uCEA0] 160123 %uBC0D%uC2A4 (%uC218%uC544)
>   %uC6B0%uB9AC.mp4'

How can I handle this correctly so I can access non-english named files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a string encoding problem, read: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this; I tested it and it doesn't have that problem:

In browser (JQuery/JavaScript):

```
    function newModule() {

        var path = $("#path").val();          // Whatever value you want to be sent.

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'modules' %}",       // Handler as defined in Django URLs. 
            type: "POST",                     // Method.
            dataType: "json",                 // Format as JSON (Default).
            data: {
                path: path,                   // Dictionary key (JSON). 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: 
                         '{{ csrf_token }}'   // Unique key.
            },

            success: function (json) {

                // On success do this.

            },

            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

                // On failure do this. 

            }

        });
```

In server engine (Python):

```
def handle(request):

    # Post request containing the key.  
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'path' in request.POST.keys():

        # Retrieving the value.
        current_title = request.POST['path']
        # You can also do |ttl = current_title.encode('utf-8')| to make sure.

    # ...
```

Comment: Brilliant, It worked perfectly. Much appreciated! Marked it as the correct answer.